# Installing VMware on ubuntu 14.04 help needed

Tags: helpfile

I have downloaded the VMware Player for Linux 64-bit from its [official site](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/3_0)  and details:

- Binary Details.bundle Installation file for 64-bit Linux
- Build Number: 744570
- Release Date: 2012-06-13
- CHECKSUMSMD5SUM: d0715a06775c0f92b9d23e031e4af1c6
- SHA1SUM: 5033c1bfecb309b96399410e614c41452c49e8e8

Now the problem is how do I install it.

I read  the tutorial and to install I had to run the following commands:

```
chmod +x ./VMware-Player-3.1.6-744570.x86_64.bundle
```

but I am getting following errors

```
rishabh@rishabh-Lenovo-G580:~$ chmod +x ./VMware-Player-3.1.6-744570.x86_64.bundle
chmod: cannot access ‘./VMware-Player-3.1.6-744570.x86_64.bundle’: No such file or directory
rishabh@rishabh-Lenovo-G580:~$
```

so now what to do to install as I downloaded and the file is in `.bundle` format. I don't know what to do as I had only one command to install it and I guess I am mistaking in x86_64 in  the command, if its not the correct syntax then please help me.

---

if you could help me then please help me now as i am stuck in : VMware Kernel Module UPdater....... it gives an error as unable to build kernel module See log file /tmp/vmware-root/setup-3916.log for details. –  NApaLM 99 10 hours ago

use : sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-uname -r –  Ashu 52 mins ago

i tried it but i am getting the following errors::::rishabh@rishabh-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-uname Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-uname rishabh@rishabh-Lenovo-G580:~$ –  NApaLM 99 16 mins ago

are u trying to say this:sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) –  NApaLM 99 3 mins ago   edit

if that then sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) [sudo] password for rishabh: Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done build-essential is already the newest version. linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic is already the newest version. The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: dkms dnsmasq kde-l10n-engb libappindicator1 libindicator7 Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 397 not upgraded. rishabh@rishabh-Lenovo-G580:~$ –  NApaLM 99 1 min ago   edit

Comment: use ./VMware-Player-3.1.6-744570.x86_64.bundle

Comment: Make sure you are typing filename correctly and your present working directory in terminal is same as where your download file is. If you are still getting error post the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Right click to **.bundle file** **>>** properties **>>** permission. and select "**all to execute program**"

open terminal terminal go to folder you have vmware file. considering in **download folder**

eg. `cd Downloads`

now type :- `sudo ./VMware-Player-3.1.6-744570.x86_64.bundle`

Comment: if you could help me then please help me now as i am stuck in : VMware Kernel Module UPdater....... it gives an error as                                                unable to build kernel module See log file /tmp/vmware-root/setup-3916.log for details.

Comment: use : sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`

Comment: i tried it but i am getting the following errors::::rishabh@rishabh-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-uname
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-uname
rishabh@rishabh-Lenovo-G580:~$

Comment: are u trying to say this:sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Comment: if that then  sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
[sudo] password for rishabh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms dnsmasq kde-l10n-engb libappindicator1 libindicator7
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 397 not upgraded.
rishabh@rishabh-Lenovo-G580:~$